# IPFS URI to tas.bytes

Tags: taquito

How can I properly pass an an IPFS URI to Taquito's `tas.bytes`helper?

tas.bytes("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmeyjRSnCmWCtfV7jdrdSbY1druBA4hVYmXzdMAYowh74q") doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think that is not an IPFS URI, the right format should be `ipfs://QmeyjRSnCmWCtfV7jdrdSbY1druBA4hVYmXzdMAYowh74q`. Can you try that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that specific taquito method, but you can use `Bytes` from the archetype ts-types library. e.g:

```
import { Bytes } from "@completium/archetype-ts-types";

const URI_as_bytes : Bytes = Bytes.hex_encode("ipfs://bafybeigzpfsrvvb3ifrfe4tmahmenuf3flbyhi5y4v6g4fn6pqpiqd4wwy")
```